# Wii Sensor Bar With PC

Tags: wii

I have a Bluetooth adapter for PC and I can setup the Wiimote buttons as keyboard actions and control things like media center with the Wiimote.

But to be able to use the Wiimote as a mouse, I need a sensor bar. I have a sensor bar that came with the Wii, but to be able to use it with my PC, I need to attach it to my Wii, turn on the Wii and place the sensor bar in front of my monitor.

There is a [hack to make the sensor bar wall powered](http://jdandison.wordpress.com/2008/06/03/wall-powered-wii-sensor-bar/), but to do this I would need to cut the wire and I need the sensor bar to still be able to connect to the Wii.

<s>Basically, I was wondering if there was an adapter that allows you to connect the sensor bar to the wall without hacking up the wire.

Or if there was a wireless sensor bar that someone has successfully used to control the PC mouse with the Wiimote.</s>

Actually, I'm willing to buy a new Nintendo brand sensor bar, but I was wondering if there was a way to make it USB powered instead of wall powered. I don't have a 7.5v DC adapter lying around and they're actually more expensive than the sensor itself.

Answer (score 5):

In the meantime, you can light two candles and set them up by your monitor. The infrared light they give off will work to simulate a sensor bar.

Plus, it's romantic.

Comment: Actually I've tried this, it works but it's a tad glitchy and I have to re-calibrate the Wiimote everytime I want to play a game or use it as a mouse. Not to mention all the wax and what not.

Comment: +1 for the romance. But yes, there should be a better fix.

Answer (score 4):

You can purchase sensor bars from third-party manufacturers, including battery- and USB-powered models. For example, the [Nextronics USB Sensor Bar](http://www.nextronicsllc.com/shop/sensorbar.php) (I haven't used this particular product, it's just the first one I came across).

I have been surprised by the number of useful accessories I've seen at stores that sell consoles and console games, so you might find one there. Similarly, online stores that sell consoles list these kind of accessories too, trying searching for "`usb sensor bar`".

Comment: Since my question, I've actually bought a third-party sensor bar installed it to be powered from a standard socket. =)

Comment: @RyanScottLewis good news :) could you accept my answer, or if it's now too specific (USB), write your own?